# Is there an official LUIS API that returns the total number of Utterances for each intent?

Tags: c#, api, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-sdk-.net

I noticed the LUIS portal (www.luis.ai) shows Intents with the total number of Utterances for each.  I'm looking to build a similar page in my application, although Microsoft's published APIs don't have a method that returns the total utterances per intent.

We noticed the LUIS dashboard is using this API to pull the data, but the method is not published in their docs:
`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/webapi/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{version}/stats/labelsperintent`

Does anyone know whether this is an official API that can be used?  We don't want to use it and then Microsoft makes changes to it later which could break our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint you discovered is not an official API. Notice that it's `luis/webapi/v2.0` instead of `luis/api/v2.0`. You can use it, but like you said you run the risk of it changing later.

I recommend using the [example utterances - Review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a) API: `https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/examples[?skip][&take]`. You would just need to query the data yourself to see the utterance count for each intent.