# LUIS API call to get list of Utterances for an intent is failing with 404 error

Tags: c#, api, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-sdk-.net

We're looking to access a list of "utterances" for a specific intent using Azure SDK v3 for Cognitive Services (LUIS), but the method is returning "404 Resource Not Found".  This is the method we are calling "ExamplesMethodWithHttpMessagesAsync".  You can see it on this page below on line # 2619:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/cognitiveservices/Language.LUIS.Authoring/src/Generated/Model.cs#L2579

Note:  We see a similar method that is used in the LUIS portal (www.luis.ai), but I'm not sure if that web API is safe for us to use.  Nonetheless, it's odd the SDK method call is failing for us.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to proceed to get the utterances for a specific intent?

Comment: What are you passing as `modelId`?

Comment: I'm passing IntentId, but I noticed you opened a github issue about this already (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6868).  Much appreciated.  I will wait a couple weeks and hopefully it should be resolved by then.

Comment: That's good. In the meantime, please remember to upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but I am told that the fix should be deployed by the end of the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this API can be found in the Azure SDK, [it is not a publicly exposed endpoint](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6868).

As I said in your [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937022/is-there-an-official-luis-api-that-returns-the-total-number-of-utterances-for-ea), for now you will have to use the [Review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a) API.